# SpringBoot MAVEN and MongoDB -Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on a small project where I plan to show some documents from my database. I'm havinf this problem where springboot refers to my controller as a bean .
here's my actual bean.

```
public class ProductBean {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String reference;
    private String libelle;
    @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
    private float price;
    private String marque;
    private int stock;
    private String image;
```

and My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class ProductController {

    private ProductRepository prodRepo;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<ProductBean> getAll() {
     ..
    }
    @GetMapping("categories/{category}/all")
    public List<ProductBean>getAllByCategory(@PathVariable String category) {...}
```

My repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductBean,String> {}
```

the Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController' defined in file [E:\IntelijProj\target\classes\irisi\bdss\catalog\controllers\ProductController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in irisi.bdss.catalog.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type ProductBean!
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]

Thank you for your help. I've been very bummed about this.

Comment: in this section you try to add annotation @Autowired private ProductRepository prodRepo;

Comment: What package is your `ProductBean`?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe it's in the com.example.app.bean package.

Comment: @hirarqi I already did but it's still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

It was one of the queries in another file. don't use the @Query format next time!